# Matplotlib bar graphs: increase spacing between bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib and it seems like there's no direct method for increasing the space between bars in a bar graph rendering of data. There are posts on this but the responses say that one has to play with the width of bars or the scale of the x axis which is not what I'm looking for because that will just make my bar skinnier or lead to overlapping and scaling the x axis wouldn't work for non-numerical tick values (right?). I would specifically like to increase the space between the bars which makes sense for the data below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar('state','n_incidents',data=top_5_gun_violence_states)
plt.xlabel('States')
plt.ylabel('# of incidents')
plt.title('Statewise gun violence graph')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
# plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this: 
[matplotlib bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEBZr.png)

Clearly, this needs more spacing between bars as state names are squeezed together. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't making the bars wider allow more space for text?  Have you tried making the font smaller?

Comment: @Plato77 making the bars wider using the width parameter causes bars to overlap. Making the font smaller renders the text illegible. I'm writing my code in a Jupyter notebook so I'm trying to see now if Jupyter is causing this issue.

Comment: ah ok - try `plt.save_html` and then check the formatting of the html: https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_html.  Also, you may be able to choose a different renderer: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html

Comment: @Plato77 I followed the link for saving to html but unfortunately it didn't do much to help the problem. What did help though is setting plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,4) which allowed me to vary the size of the figure rendered; I could space out the x-axis that was getting crammed before and state names are legible now. This method also made the bars wider without overlapping but it did not effectively increase the space between bars. I just wish matplotlib had some method or some other way of achieving this. Anyways, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: have you tried plotly?

Comment: I haven't recently but I've used it briefly in the past. Visualizations are much better with plotly, right?